# Why wasn't Metushelach saved?

Tags: tzaddikim, mabul, noach-noah-the-man

In parshat Noach, Hashem (according to [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.7.4?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en)) delays the rain so that [Metushelach's](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/68264/who-was-methuselah) shiv'a period could be honored,

> These are the seven days of mourning for the righteous man Methuselah for whose honour the Holy One, blessed be He. had regard, and therefore postponed punishment. Go and calculate the years of Methuselah and you will find that they came to an end (i. e. he died) in the six hundredth year of Noah’s life (which coincided with the date of the Flood) (Sanhedrin 108b).

Rashi calls him a Tzaddik. [This](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11864/moses-lived-120-years-and-tradition-says-no-one-can-live-longer-so-why-do-they/11871#11871) answer cites (without real source) the statement that there were

> seven long-lived saints whose successive lives extend over the whole history of mankind; each having transmitted the sacred lore from his predecessor to the one succeeding him, **while shielding the generations of his time by means of his piety.** These saints are: (1) Adam; (2) Methuselah;

(bolding mine)

[This](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/47274/1362) answer discusses sainted individuals in the context of belief in God and lists him.

Whereas [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/87624/who-are-the-seven-shepherds-at-the-end-of-maoz-tzur/87630#87630) Q/A lists him (according to some opinions) as a "shepherd".

If he was such a tzaddik/saint/shepherd/believer, so much so that Hashem delayed His actions to respect his mourning period, why was he not saved with Noach (or why was he not the one who was spoken to 120 years earlier and warned about the flood)?

Comment: What was there to be saved from if he died before the flood?

Comment: If he was so much a tzaddik, he could have been the one Hashem spoke to initially, or he could have been saved simply to reward his righteousness. I guess it could be that the rain couldn't start until he died (in which case, in a sense, he was MORE righteous than Noach).

Comment: Asking why someone wasn't saved implies that something bad happened to them. Yet I don't see any indication in your question that anything bad happened to him. Everyone dies at some point. He lived his life and then died. What else should have happened?

Comment: Nothing bad happened because Hashem pushed off punishment in his z'chut. If that's the case, then he (I would think) merited more than he got. Not being the avenue through which people are saved indicates a deficiency though when compared to Noach, he is possibly superior.

Comment: If anything that would show that he is *greater* than Noach – the entire world was kept alive for as long ass he lived. In what sense then was he not "saved"?

Comment: That's part of my problem (see my earlier comment) -- was he too good to be saved? Noach was tamim but Met. who was superior wasn't?

Comment: Let's grant that Methushelach was superior. What would you have liked to happen to him? He lived his life completely. He died like every other righteous person in history has. He even had the entire world saved for an extra week in his merit. Adam also wasn't "saved" because he died long before the flood occurred. Avraham also wasn't saved because he was born after the flood occurred. In what sense was Methushelach less saved than these other two figures?

Comment: Saved from what? Seems like he died a natural death before the flood.

Comment: @Dude because the flood was pushed off. He merited changing the entire timing of the flood but not a seat on the boat?

Comment: @Alex 120 years earlier he didn't deserve a conversation from Hashem (which might have led to his inspiring others to teshuva, something which Noach didn't do)? He was more righteous than Noach! Hashem chose the second best as his emissary?

Comment: So your question is not "why wasn't he saved?", but "why wasn't he used as an emissary?"

Comment: I fold the two together.

Comment: It was pushed off out if respect for him to have time for mourning. Why do you think he should have had his life extended past the time of the flood? Even if this were to happen perhaps this wouldn't have been a blessing for someone so advanced in age to see the whole world he grew up with destoryed?

Comment: I would think that, first, it wouldn't have to be pushed off if his lifespan was known by God (the mabul could have come whenever Hashem wanted it to and a tzaddik like Met. could have been saved had the rain come earlier), second he could have been a more effective emissary to inspire teshuva, third, 120 years earlier, when Noach was notified, he would have been also.

Comment: I think he died right before the Mabbul, in the same year.

Answer (score 3):

One of the reasons for not having the flood in that time is part of what we see from Avraham and his asking for S'dom to be saved if there were *ten righteous* people. Once the count got to ten, Avraham stopped praying. We learn from this that it required a minyan (10 people) to prevent the flood. Hashem was willing to be counted as one of the ten. Noach, his wife, their three sons, and their wives were 8. Mesushelach was the tenth person whose merit prevented the flood from starting. He reached the normal end of his life and died. Since there was noone to replace him, the flood could no longer be postponed. However, out of respect for him, Hashem waited the extra seven days until his mourning period was completed.

Rashi explains on [Vayeira 18:32](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8213/jewish/Chapter-18.htm#v=32&showrashi=true)

> **perhaps ten will be found there:** For fewer [than ten] he did not ask. He said, “In the Generation of the Flood, there were eight: Noah
>   and his sons, and their wives, but they did not save their
>   generation.” And for nine, together with counting [God] he had already
>   asked, but did not find.

Comment: the first question I cited lists people in whose merit a generation was protected. #3 is Shem. He was alive before the mabul began and yet the waters came. So not only were the 2 alive at the time, but Shem's "protection" didn't work. Met was clearly superior in merits. Why didn't hashem save him (or any of his other sons and daughters besides his one grandson's family).

Comment: @rosends it was not an individual but a minyon that was needed, similar to S'dom and Abraham.

Comment: @Kazibácsi I added the citation from Rashi which shows (by implication) that while Mesushelach was alive there were nine plus Hashem to keep the flood from coming.

Comment: This is interesting from the perspective that in regard to the generation of the flood, it includes both men & women. And yet, the concept of being counted in a Minyan today does not include women. Are you suggesting that by non-Jews, women get included equally too men, but among Jews that is not the case? Additionally, what is the idea of including G-d in the count? Halacha doesn't follow that idea either. And the Rashi in Hebrew says, "וְעַל ט' עַל יְדֵי צֵרוּף כְּבָר בִּקֵּשׁ וְלֹא מָצָא:". "On 9 through 'tzeruf' he (meaning Avraham) already asked..." That seems to be about another time.

Comment: @sabbahillel What is this idea of 'Tzeruf' that Rashi is referring to and when did that  event occur? The English translation adds mention of G-d, but that isn't in the Rashi and even if it were wouldn't make sense. To my knowledge, no-one follows that idea.